# How to update existent Facebook post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to update Facebook post from WindowsPhone application.
I didn't find any mentions in documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Create/Delete works just fine but in my case I need to UPDATE previously published post.

I tried to Post to /post_id path

```
var fb = new FacebookClient(_token);
dynamic result = await fb.PostTaskAsync(
                        "/" + _postId,
                        new { message = "test update!" });
```

but got the following error:

> Facebook.FacebookOAuthException: (OAuthException - #100) (#100)
>   Requires one of the params:
>
> > is_hidden,is_published,scheduled_publish_time,is_pinned,timeline_visibility,backdated_time

If I add is_published flag:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient(_token);
dynamic result = await fb.PostTaskAsync(
    "/" + _lastPostId,
    new {
            message = "test update!",
            is_published = true
        });
```

I got another error:

> (OAuthException - #100) (#100) Unsupported post request

Thanks for any suggests!

Comment: I was able to make POST request which returns valid response ('true') but my Post message wasn't updated

`var fb = new FacebookClient(_token);
dynamic result = await fb.PostTaskAsync(
    "/" + _lastPostId,
    new {
            message = "test update!",
            timeline_visibility = 'normal'
        });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that neither Facebook nor Twitter provides the ability to update posts.
Only VK (Vkontakte social network) has such an ability (wall.edit)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered recently, you can edit the message of a post on a public page if the type of the post is link

Or you can update the state of a post by making it hidden, starred or visible by:

POST : https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID?is_hidden={hidden|normal|starred}

More about this you can find [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#links).